# Running unit tests before each build in Gradle

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, build.gradle

How can I configure a `build.gradle` in an Android project to run all my unit tests before each debug or release build? I know that I can set tasks dependencies with `dependsOn`, but how can I specify it for the unit test task? I'd like to do this for each (Android and plain Java) module of my project, is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you have a special task to run only unit tests? Or you are free to run it as simple `test` (or more generally `testDebug` and `testRelease`)? Let's say, you want to run `testDebug` or `testRelease` every time you call `assembleDebug` or `assembleRelease` task. Then you can, as you've noted, use `dependsOn` task property. For example this way:

```
assembleDebug.dependsOn testDebug
assembleRelease.dependsOn testRelease
```

This configuration must be added to every build.gradle script (in every module of the project), where you need it. If you have a number of test tasksm you can set task dependencies this way:

```
tasks.assembleRelease.dependsOn {
    project.tasks.findAll { task ->
        task.name.startsWith('testRelease')
    }
}
```

Sure, you can try to set this dependencies in the root the root build.gradle script, by using `allprojects` or `subprojects` (you can read about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:cross_project_configuration)), but you have to apply `android` plugin in the root script too, otherwise tasks won't be found.

Comment: I have a project with both Android and plain Java modules. I only have simple JUnit tests for now. In my plain Java modules everything seems to work fine with `jar.dependsOn test` at the end of the gradle file (if a test fails, the build stops). In my Android modules, with `assembleDebug.dependsOn testDebug` I get the error `Could not find property 'testDebug' on BuildType_Decorated`. Where should I put this line? Thanks!